# Twig escapes my HTML even when autoescape is false (FuelPHP Configuration)

Tags: php, html, escaping, twig, fuelphp

when trying to **ouput HTML** with [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) *(and [FuelPHP](http://fuelphp.com/))*, I get escaped HTML, even when `autoescape` value is to `false` (config file or directly in the template...)

Here's my Twig template:

```
{% set id_page = 'visio_page' %}
{% include 'layout/header.twig' %}
    <div id="main">
        <div class="inner">
        {% autoescape false %} 
            {{form}} {# or form|raw #}
        {% endautoescape %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% include 'layout/footer.twig' %}
```

Here's my form variable I give to Twig:

```
$data['form'] = $fieldset->form()->build(Uri::create('/form/submit'));
//output is only HTML: '<form>......</form>';
```

That is the result I have... 
[image: The result show only escaped HTML, not form.]

**I usually use** `{{my_var|raw}}` **but it does not work in this particular case ...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fuel escapes the values to views by default. And the default config is below:

```
'auto_encode' => true;  // (Fuel's auto escaping)
'autoescape'  => false; // (Twig's auto escaping)
```

[image]

If you want to change, copy `fuel/packages/parser/config/parser.php` to `fuel/app/config` directory, and change them.

Comment: I set parser.View_Twig.auto_encode to false, and it works! Thanks @kenjis! (I didn't noticed auto_encode was acting onto the autoescape thing...)